# Is it good to keep microservices with single technology or multiple?

Tags: microservices

What is the recommended approach to decide the technology to use for creating miroservice?

> **ex:** All 50 microservices running in .NET platform using SQL Server as
> DB for each one of them

OR

Mix and match between different technology

> **ex :** 15 Spring-based microservice with MongoDB, 15 .NET with SQL, 20 NodeJS microservice with Redis

[Microservice with different technology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOT8X.png)

I know this will again come down to developers who are familiar with what technology but all I am looking to know is which approach you would have taken if you have more than 50 microservices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the role of each microservice. If all of them are REST APIs with a pretty similar functionality (but completely different scope), then it would be helpful to use the same tech stack, because:

- You can optimize your development workflows
- You get more homogeneity across your entire system, which translates into a number of benefits down the road (identify/fix issues faster, optimize resource usage, etc).

However, if you have some microservices which have different constraints in terms of performance (or consistency, or any other vector), you can use a different tech stack just for that one. The architectural model of microservices allows that - it doesn't matter what's behind a microservice as long as it exposes an API that can be used by other microservices.

TL;DR - if you have strong reasons to use different tech stacks for some microservices, you should do it, but keep in mind that it doesn't come without a cost.